# Integrate ASP.Net Identity into WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, authentication

Found a great article online for getting custom authorization in WPF here: http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/24/custom-authorization-in-wpf/

My question is, if I have an existing asp.net project that has already created users can I integrate them into this authorization?

Comment: @Sheridan :) thanks, I was kind of asking for the how as well as the possibility